# Admob disabled on deleted application

Tags: android, admob

I received an e-mail from Google Admob with this message:

This email is to alert you that one of your applications is not currently in compliance with our AdMob program policies and as a result, ad serving has been disabled to your application.

Issue ID#: #######

Ad serving has been disabled to: c########################

Action required: Check all other remaining applications in your account for compliance.

Current account status: Active

I have only 1 app published on Google Play and the package name in the message is the suspended app on Developer Console. The published app uses the same Admob ID banner that the deleted app. What should I do now? Upload an update of the current app with new ID banner? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, every ad should have a different Ad Unit ID. This includes ads for different apps or ads within the same app. You should create a new ad and link it to your app in the play store, then update the app with the new Ad Unit ID.

You should also ensure you are following AdSence's guidelines [AdSence Program Policies](https://support.google.com/adsense/answer/48182?utm_source=aso&utm_medium=link&utm_campaign=ww-ww-et-asfe_&hl=en) and [Implementation Guidance](https://support.google.com/admob/answer/2936217?hl=en&ref_topic=2745287).

Comment: Yes, I use 2 IDs for the 2 banners but are the same IDs that I used in the suspended app. Thanks :)

If I do nothing Google will delete my Admob account and also the Developer account?

Comment: AdSense "reserves the right to disable your account for any reason", but I believe that's generally only if they think you're scamming them with activity like clicking your own ads, etc. Likely, they will only disable serving ads to those two IDs, and you'll have to make more.

Comment: So, I must assume that the ad units will be disabled on the current app? Very subjective Google with the suspensions. Mmm =/

Comment: Yes, they likely shut down those ads by their IDs, so you must make new ones.

Comment: I see u.u Thanks for your help and advices.

Answer (score 0):

> What should I do now? Upload an update of the current app with new ID banner?

Yes. Create a new ad unit and use that in your published app.

You should make it a practice to use different ad units for each app from the beginning.

This will enable better tracking and also help in avoiding situations like this. Now in this case you'll miss on ad revenue from users till they update the app to the version which contains a new working as unit id.

Comment: The current ad units are still generating $$$ (well that's my doubt... the ad units are still generating dollars on the current app but in the old app were suspended) but like you say It's better create new IDs. Thanks :)